# Text - Empty Text Node issue in IE 8

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am using IE8 browser. It creates an empty text node after `<input /><span><textarea>` like this tags.
I cant found how rectify this. Can anybody tell me to fix this issue..?
**Code :-**

```
        <form id="addNewsForm" action="/addNews.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label>Title : </label>
            <input type="text" class="addNewsTitle" name="addNewsTitle" />
            <label>Content : </label>
            <textarea rows="10" cols="35" name="addNewsCnt" class="addNewsCnt"></textarea>
            <label>Category : </label>
            <select>
                <option>world</option>
                <option>important</option>
                <option>common</option>
                <option>tamilnadu</option>
                <option>lifestyle</option>
            </select>
            <input type="button" name="noimage" class="newsImgAdd" value="ADD IMAGE" /> 
            <input type="file" name="file" class="addNewsImg" />
            <input type="submit" class="submit addNewsSubmit" value="SUBMIT" />
            <iframe id="addNewsFrame" name="addNewsFrame"></iframe>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 shows the empty text nodes because sometimes it considers the space between two elements as Empty Text Node.

You need to remove the space between the fields.

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/uTDWD/1/

Comment: Did you check the fiddle I posted... that works. You need to click on the refresh icon in the developer toolbar of IE8 and then inspect the elements again

Comment: Can you post a URL where I can check it?

Comment: Thanks @Dipaks.. I removed the spaces after <input>,<select>,<img> tags and now the problem solved